# If statement based on invalid class entered in Python

Tags: python, class, if-statement, int

I'm quite new to python and I'm trying to create a program that uses an if statement that is based on if an int input ( `int(input())` ) gets the right input class. For example: if I have an input that goes `Var1 = int(input("Enter a number:..."))`, and the user enters `hello` there, this would, instead of giving an error message, go into one of the options in an `if` statement.

Since the rest of the code hasn't been created yet I can't post it, but I've tried all the ways I've come up with to solve this problem without success... Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What happens when the user types "hello" in this case?  Do you get an exception?  Maybe exception handling is the way forward?

Comment: Check `string.isdigit()` or `string.isalpha()` functions. That will solve your requirement.

Comment: @cdarke when you type letters when the input is an integer input you get an error, and instead of that i want to be able to divide the inputs in to two diffrent sections in an if statement, one for if the answer was an integer, the other one if it wasnt.

Comment: @voidpro could you explain how you would use those in an input. Im new to python so i don't really understand where you sugest that i put them... Should i be string.isdigit(input("Enter a number... ")) or what do you mean?

Comment: @IsacSkoglund get your input in a variable, say `x=input()`. Based on the class of `x`, you can perform the operation. You can do something like `if x.isdigit(): print("Number")` if `x` is `int`. I hope, this is what your need.

Comment: That's the point, you handle the "error" with exception handling, as in the answer given (which you should accept).

Answer (score 0):

You can surround your input with a `try..except` block and capture a `ValueError` that will occur when `int()` tries to convert a non-integer into an integer:

```
try:
    var1 = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
except ValueError:
    print("That's not an integer!")
```

You can even force your users to enter an integer by placing it in a loop:

```
var1 = None
while var1 is None:
    try:
        var1 = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not an integer!")
```

Or you can do checks at a later time:

```
var1 = input("Enter an integer: ")
try:
    var1 = int(var1)
    print("Thank you for entering an integer.")
except ValueError:
    print("That's not an integer!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try/except:

```
while(True):
    try:
        var1 = int(input("enter a number: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('it should be a number')
```

caution: don't use try/except without Execption type like:

```
try:
    printo('hi')
except:
    pass
```

it will except all excetions even syntax error

Comment: i just got the same answer from zwer aswell, and it works, thanks for the help!